# Running a root-level npm script in a workspace context

Tags: npm, npm-scripts, npm-workspaces

I have a script defined in the root-level package.json:

```json
{
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rm -rf lib dist"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I would like to run this script in the context of the the `packages/example` package, **which does not define a `clean` script**. (I want to reuse this script across all of my workspaces

I tried running `npm -w packages/example run clean` and `npm run clean -w packages/example` but these commands search for a `clean` script inside `packages/example/package.json`:

```bash
npm ERR! Error: Missing script: "clean"
```

To be clear, I want to delete the `lib` and `dist` folders from `packages/example` by running a script at the workspace root.

Note: I'm using this clean script as an example. The real scripts are more complicated and I don't want to duplicate them across all of the workspaces

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I found with this is to call it with `--include-workspace-root` option, which includes the workspace root context. The problem is that it will also try to run the script in the current package context, so if you have `clean` script defined in your `example` package it will also run. If it doesn’t have a script though it will raise an error, thankfully it could be suppressed by `--if-present` flag.

```
npm run --include-workspace-root --if-present clean
```

Comment: That works for the most part, but the script is still being run from the workspace root context, so paths are relative to the workspace root. I want them to be relative to each individual package root